# Question about changing state and rendering. React js

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I ran into such a problem and it interested me very much, I would like to get an answer to this question. The situation is as follows:

I have a project on Next js, in the root folder there are hooks in which there is `useCity.ts`, In this file I have useState (`const [city, setCity] = useState(null)`) and I return these two (`return {city , setCity}`). I also have two pages in `pages`, `/city` and `/changeCity`. In `changeCity` I use the `useCity` hook, take `setCity` from there and change `city`, in `useCity` the state changes (checked the console with a log in `useEffect`), and in `/city` I take the city state from `useCity` and draw it, but the `city` is not updated there, and even the console log does not work.

I would like to get an answer why this is so, and how to do it right in such situations. Thanks for your attention

I want to get an answer to this question and a solution to this problem.

Comment: Every time you use `useCity` you create another state. If you want to share state between components you have to use context

Comment: @Konrad is right, you can search for react context api and global state management libraries for react.